# inheritance data member between base and derived class c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

why the apple object seed data member output difference?

1. it seems fruit pointer point to fruit data member only. I can't overwrite this member in apple. why?
2. how does line B internal work? fruit pointer point to apple 's plant function and then how this function decide which seed to call?
3. at line C, does apple object pointer get static cast to fruit pointer?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>
   using namespace std;

   class fruit
   {
       public:
       int seed;
       fruit()
       {
           cout <<"fruit" <<endl;
           seed = 12;
       }

       virtual void plant()
       {
           cout << seed <<endl;
       }
   };

   class apple:public fruit
   {
       public:
       int seed;

       apple()
       {
           cout << "apple" << endl;
           seed = 15;
       }
       void plant()
       {
           cout << seed << endl;
       }
   };

   int main()
   {

       vector<fruit*> ft;
       ft.push_back(new apple());// line C

       cout << ft[0]->seed << endl; // line A
       ft[0]->plant();// line B

       apple* ap = new apple();
       cout << ap->seed <<endl; 

   }
   ```

output:

```
fruit
apple
12
15
fruit
apple
15
```

Comment: why does my first statement   "#include <iostream>" not showed completely ? how to fix it

Comment: @billz,  how did you fix my format problem?

Comment: remove `dot` after 1. 2.

Comment: Now I fixed it by placing a comment in front of the code block. And you have a real list!

Comment: What (where) are lines A, B and C?

Comment: in main function 's comment

Comment: Isn't it a good practice to generally stay away from using the same variable name in both derived and parent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. The problem is, the method functions have polymorphism but the member variables do not. So in an `apple` object, there are two `seed` variables, the `fruit::seed` is shadowed by the `apple::seed` within the functions in `apple`. However, when you are accessing the object with type `apple` using a pointer type `fruit`, you are accessing the `fruit` part of `apple`, thus the `seed` is `fruit::seed`. See the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A
{
        public:
                int v;
                virtual ~A() {}  // ensure A is polymorphic
};

class B: public A
{
        public:
                int v;
};

int main(void)
{
        A* aa = new B;

        aa->v=20;
        dynamic_cast<B*>(aa)->v=10;

        cout<<aa->v<<endl;
        cout<<dynamic_cast<B*>(aa)->v<<endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
20
10
```

Comment: therefore, in side apple object memory layout, there are two seed data members. seed takes two sizeof(int) space. right?

Comment: @cppython Yes. If you want the two classes share the same `seed`, simply remove the `seed` declaration in the inherited class. The inherited class will automatically use `seed` from the base class.